# Entity Framework primary keys behavior

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm new to Entity Framework. I don't fully understand yet how primary keys work.

For example, say I have the following entities with an `Int` key:

```
letter1 with Key 1
letter2 with Key 2
letter3 with Key 3
```

If during the program I remove `letter2`, does `letter3` key change to 2? Or does it stay 3?

If so, what's the best practice for web api applications? I populate letters with ids to client, and when pressed, an http request for the letter with the specific id is request. However if Entity Framework automatically changes the primary keys how is this supposed to work?

In general, do primary keys value stay the same during the whole runtime?

Comment: Unclear, show an example code of your data classes.

Comment: The purpose of the key is to be never changed. so it's unique forever. if you remove an entity with key 2 it will never have effect on other keys. It is a common behavior for keys ( has nothing to do with entity framework).

Comment: Also wondering why not test it yourself in localhost *whistle whistle*

Comment: EF **never** changes primary key values - and you shouldn't, either! A PK should be assigned **once**, then a row is created - and should stay the same forever

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure